# Setting default sorted column in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on datatable plugin in Jquery. And have to set the default column by which the data is sorted so I mean that :

I have a table with 4 columns and by default the data is sorted by column no 1, I want that the data should be sorted by column number 2 or 3.

How that can be done:

```
$('#tblMainTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "sDom" : 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip<',
    "aoColumns" : [ 
        {"bSortable" : false}, 
        null, 
        null,
        null,
        {"bSortable" : false}, 
        {"bSortable" : false}
    ],
    "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
});
```

I specified that in "aaSorting" but not getting the result.

Please shed some light?

Comment: http://live.datatables.net/amipoq/8/edit this at least works, seems problem somewhere else

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The example in the [datatable api](http://datatables.net/api) does it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
  oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
} );
```

Comment: I want to sort the table on 2 column not on 0 or 1

Answer (score 7):

I know you have the answer now, but here is an even more easier way from the DatatTable API

```
$('#tblMainTable').dataTable({
    "order": [[1, "desc"], [2, "desc"]]
});
```

Do note that the index is from 0 'Zero' so the example means "Column 2 and 3 is the default sorting column and its Descending (use asc for Ascending)."

Comment: oTable.fnSort() was giving an error. But your solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know you got the answer, but just for record

You can also sort it from server side by using the parameter

```
params.iSortCol_0
```

it is basically an integer 0,1,2.. means first,second,third.. column. so you can write a switch before fetching the data..

```
 String sortOn = 'firstcolumnname'; //default
 switch(params.iSortCol_0 as int) {

   case 0:
     sortOn = 'id';
     break;
  ......

  }
```

and include this in order by of your query

```
 order by ${sortOn}
```

Hope this will help